# add and update customer

Tags: customer, import, export

I need to add new or update the customer db. I must to synchronize the customer db of magento with a another db.

I need make this each 24h.

I think this:

- if entity_id exist into db magento i update all fields
- if entity id not exist into db magento i insert the new customer

it's correct?

there is a script for update or add new customers?

Comment: `

thanks a lot.

i have tried the script but

Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /srv/www/vhosts/domain-com/app/Mage.php on line 463
` comment by @Alessandro Gnola

Answer (score 1):

Depends how the correlation is made between magento customer and your other db.
You can create a new customer attribute, let's say otherdb_customer_id. If the ids are the same, then you don't need this attribute.

And, to import you can use this extension: http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/customers.html

This is how you use it:

```
    $rowData = array(
        array(
           'otherdb_customer_id'       => $arrCustomer['customer_id'],
           '_website'                  => 'YOUR_WEBSITE_NAME',
           '_store'                    => 'YOUR_STORE_NAME',
           'email'                     => $arrCustomer['email_address'],
           'group_id'                  => '1', //PRIVAT (must have the id of the group not the string value)
           'disable_auto_group_change' => 0,
           'firstname'                 => $arrCustomer['firstname'],
           'middlename'                => '',
           'lastname'                  => $arrCustomer['lastname'],
           'password_hash'             => $arrCustomer['password'],
           'taxvat'                    => '',
           'gender'                    => $arrCustomer['gender'],
           'customer_activated'        => 'yes',
           'is_subscribed'             => 0,
           'prefix'                    => $arrCustomer['prefix'],
           '_address_prefix'           => $arrCustomer['prefix'],
           '_address_firstname'        => $arrCustomer['firstname'],
           '_address_middlename'       => '',
           '_address_lastname'         => $arrCustomer['lastname'],
           '_address_street'           => $arrCustomer['street'],
           '_address_city'             => $arrCustomer['city'],
           '_address_country_id'       => $arrCustomer['iso_code'],
           '_address_postcode'         => $arrCustomer['postcode'],
           '_address_telephone'        => $arrCustomer['telephone'],
           '_address_company'          => $arrCustomer['company'],
           '_address_fax'              => $arrCustomer['fax'],
           '_address_house_number'     => $arrCustomer['house_nr'],
           '_address_default_billing_' => 1,
           '_address_default_shipping_'=> 0,
    ),
    array(
           '_website'                  => null,
           'email'                     => null,
           '_address_prefix'           => $arrCustomer['prefix'],
           '_address_firstname'        => $arrCustomer['firstname'],
           '_address_middlename'       => '',
           '_address_lastname'         => $arrCustomer['lastname'],
           '_address_street'           => $arrCustomer['street'],
           '_address_city'             => $arrCustomer['city'],
           '_address_country_id'       => $arrCustomer['iso_code'],
           '_address_postcode'         => $arrCustomer['postcode'],
           '_address_telephone'        => $arrCustomer['telephone'],
           '_address_company'          => $arrCustomer['company'],
           '_address_fax'              => $arrCustomer['fax'],
           '_address_house_number'     => $arrCustomer['house_nr'],
           '_address_default_billing_' => 0,
           '_address_default_shipping_'=> 1,
    )
);

    try {
        $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
        $import->setIgnoreDuplicates(false);
        $import->processCustomerImport($rowData);
    } catch (Exception $e) {                    
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
```

If you need to update a customer, you can maybe change the code a bit, in that extension to handle updates, if it does not allready.

Comment: thanks a lot.

i have tried the script but

Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /srv/www/vhosts/domain-com/app/Mage.php on line 463

Comment: Have you copied the extension in your app folder ? Is it enabled ? Where you run your script, you included Mage.php and then Mage::app(); that if its not inside magento environment..